# Mysql Call Stored procedure from another stored procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I am sorry for the incomplete information.
Here's my two sp's:
SP1 -

> DELIMITER $$
>
> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP1` $$   CREATE PROCEDURE
>   `SP1`(InputCustomerID int, InputOrderID int)   BEGIN
>
> // Some sql statements and finally put it into the actual table tb1 in
>   the database
>
> END $$
>
> DELIMITER ;

SP2 - In SP2 i am assigning input value of SP1's params.

> DELIMITER $$
>
> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP2` $$   CREATE PROCEDURE `SP2`()   BEGIN
>
> Declare InputCustomerID int;   Declare InputOrderID int;   Declare
>   OrderStateDate Datetime;
>
> Select CustomerID into InputCustomerID From Cusomers   Where
>   CustomerID NOT IN (Select FK_CustomerID From CustomerOrders)   and
>   IsApproved = True   and CustomerID IN 
>       (Select FK_CustomerID From CustomerProductOrders 
>       Where Date  (OrderStartDate) = Date(Now()));
>
> Select OrderID into InputOrderID From CustomerOrders   Where
>   FK_CustomerID NOT IN (Select FK_CustomerID From CustomerProdcutOrders)
>   and IsApproved = True   and Date(OrderStartDate) = Date(Now());
>
> Call SP1(InputCustomerID, InputOrderID);
>
> END $$
>
> DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, this code works fine there was some other syntactical error.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very poorly worded, and it makes given a good answer very hard.

For example, I gather you must be calling sp2, which calls sp1. Anything else would make it impossible to feed sp1 the parameters.

You go on to say that sp2 doesn't have any input or output parameters. With no output parameters, I can't understand how you're expecting to see output from sp2.

I'm sure that, "You're not getting output because you didn't setup any output," is not the answer you wanted. You should edit your question, perhaps with some example code.